# How to communicate with an UART?

Tags: python, uart

I am trying to execute a python file, i am a beginner in python, I installed the WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4,  I open the WinPython Command Prompt.exe, I try to execute this file:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM4')  # open serial port
print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
ser.write(b'hello')     # write a string
ser.close()             # close port
```

The result that I have is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    ser = serial.Serial('COM4')  # open serial port
  File "C:\Users\user\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 38, in __init__
    SerialBase.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\serial\serialutil.py", line 282, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "C:\Users\user\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\python-2.7.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 66, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port %r: %r" % (self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM4': WindowsError(5, 'Access is denied.')
```

I don't understand really the problem.

I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You should run this script with administrator privilege

Comment: I did that i mean that i open the the WinPython Command Prompt.exe as an adminitrator but i found the same error.

Comment: Do you have another program running that is using the same port?

Comment: Yes I use Tera, when I stopped it, my script works correctly thank you very much.